# Constraining a div's size to avoid overflow, when it contains an img

Tags: css, frontend, css-grid

I'm struggling to constrain the height of a row in a grid layout. I'm constraining the height of this highest level wrapper div, and would like to have no overflow. This grid contains:

1. A wrapper div, that contains

   - A `img` element
   - A div that has a small fixed height
2. A div that should take max-content height

```html
<div style='border: 1px solid black; height: 170px; width: 200px; display: grid; grid-auto-flow: row; grid-template-rows: auto max-content'>
  <div style='border: 1px solid blue; width: 100%'>
    <div style='border: 1px solid green; width: 100%'>
      <img style='border: 1px solid pink; height: 100%; width: 100%' src='https://img.rasset.ie/00124791-1200.jpg' />
    </div>
    <div style='border: 1px solid purple; height: 25px; width: 180px'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style='border: 1px solid red; height: 100px; width: 190px' />
</div>

<div style="height: 5rem"></div>

<div style='border: 1px solid black; height: 170px; width: 200px; display: grid; grid-auto-flow: row'>
  <div style='border: 1px solid blue; width: 150px'>
    <div style='border: 1px solid green; width: 160px'>
      <img style='border: 1px solid pink; height: 20px; width: 170px; object-fit: cover' src='https://img.rasset.ie/00124791-1200.jpg' />
    </div>
    <div style='border: 1px solid purple; height: 25px; width: 180px'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style='border: 1px solid red; height: 100px; width: 190px' />
</div>
```

Currently the image pushes its parent div to be as tall as needed given its width and the image's aspect ratio. I would like to have the image cropped if there's not enough space to fit. I could hardcode the height, and that would constrain the img element, but that means the grid (highest level wrapper) isn't filled to its entire height.

How might I let the `img` element resize flexibly?

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a solution that works around the weird way `img` elements are handled inside `div`s, by making the image a `div` with an image background instead.

You can see in the code below that the image area resizes to take up the rest of space flexibly, based on the sizes for other sections (30px grey and 50px red)

```html
<style>
  .imgDiv {
    background-image: url(https://img.rasset.ie/00128cd0-300.jpg);
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover
  }

  .flexBox {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
</style>

<div class='flexBox' style='border: 1px solid black; height: 170px; width: 200px;'>
  <div class='flexBox' style='background: blue; flex-grow: 1; display: flex'>
    <div class='imgDiv'>
    </div>
    <div style='background: grey; height: 30px'></div>
  </div>
  <div style='background: red; height: 50px;'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main concept is to understand how to place an image in a div element,  if the image is a child element and you specified the fixed width of a that div element/wrapper then the image will fit in that div by putting a width of image element as 100% and not 170px because the div/wrapper is already 170px otherwise the over flow will still exist.

Comment: I don't understand what this would mean practically - I can't specify a fixed height but cannot have a fixed width either? At some point some parent container will have some width constraint